# Jquery Div slide transitions From Right To Left not working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create one page transitions in jquery like "http://support.microsoft.com/" this.

My problem is when page transitions done, it start from left. Please refer this fiddle (**[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/6r6Y6/)**) and you can understand what happen. First I click on "Page 1" from drop down menu. First div comes from right to left (←) and its perfect, then after I click on text from First Div and Second Div comes from right to left (←), this also perfect. after that I click on text from second Div and third Div come from right to left (←) and Div 1 and 2 goes hide @ left side, that's fine. but now problem start. when I click on "page 1" from navigation, My hidden divs come from left to right (→) in place of right to left (←). What I should I do ?

**Here Is my Code**

**HTML**

```
    <div class="codrops-top clearfix">
        <!-- <a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon-prev" href=""><span>Previous Demo</span></a>
        <span class="right"><a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon-drop" href=""><span>Back to the Codrops Article</span></a></span> -->

    </div>

    <div class="pt-wrapper">
        <div class="pt-trigger-container">
            <div class="navigation right">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src = "menu.png" width = "25">
                        <div style = "margin-left:10px">
                            <ul>
                                <li id = "page1"><a>Page 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id = "container1" style="left:80%;background:#98bf21;height:100%;width:200px;position:absolute;display:none">
        <ul id = "contaoneritem1">
            <li><a>Content 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 2</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 3</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 4</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 5</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id = "container2" style="left:80%;background:#98bf21;height:100%;width:200px;position:absolute;display:none">
        <ul id = "contaoneritem2">
            <li><a>Content 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.3</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.4</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.5</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id = "container3" style="left:80%;background:#98bf21;height:100%;width:600px;position:absolute;display:none">
        <ul id = "contaoneritem3">
            <li><a>Content 1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.2.1</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.4.1</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.5.1</a></li>
            <li><a>Content 1.6.1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{overflow:hidden}
    .navigation ul{ float:right;}
    .navigation ul li{ float:left; padding:0px 300px 0px 5px;cursor:pointer}
    .navigation ul li a{cursor:pointer}
    .navigation ul li div{ display:none;}
    .navigation ul li:hover div{ display:block; position:absolute;z-index:9999}
    .navigation ul li:hover div ul{ float:none; margin-left:-30px;}
    .navigation ul li:hover div ul li{ float:none; text-align:left; padding:0px; background:#110000; border-bottom:#dddddd solid 1px;}
    .navigation ul li:hover div ul li:hover a{ background:#fff; color:black}
    .navigation ul li:hover div ul li a{ padding:3px 5px; display:block; width:100%;color:white}
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#page1").click(function(){
        var div3=$("#container3");  
        div3.animate({left:'120%'},"slow");
      $("#container1").show();
        var div=$("#container1");  
        div.animate({left:'20%'},"slow");
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#contaoneritem1").click(function(){
      $("#container2").show();
        var div=$("#container2");  
        div.animate({left:'40%'},"slow");
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#contaoneritem2 li a").click(function(){
        var div=$("#container2");  
        var div1=$("#container1");  
        div.animate({left:'-100%'},"slow");
        div1.animate({left:'-100%'},"slow");
        $("#container3").show();
        var div3=$("#container3");  
        div3.animate({left:'20%'},"slow");
      });
    });
```

Comment: bcaz once ur div1 & 2 hides they goes into -left suppose -20 and if u animate it by 20 they will be than its -20 +20 = 0 so they will come up from the left side.

Comment: @Neha can u pls update that in my fiddle ?

Comment: you can try this tutorial for better result

http://www.themeswild.com/read/slide-navigation-left-to-right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are moving the container 1& 2 to extrem left thats why it start coming from left to right, do following changes :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#page1").click(function(){
var div3=$("#container3");  
div3.animate({left:'120%'},"slow");
var div2=$("#container2");  
var div1=$("#container1"); 
 div2.css("left", "100%");
 div1.css("left", "80%");
$("#container1").show();
var div=$("#container1");  
div.animate({left:'20%'},"slow");
});
});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6r6Y6/2/)

Comment: Oh yes, thank you dear, that's what exactly I want. thank you once more